# JMeter - Big image not downloaded in the scrpt

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter script for a page which has many js and images. For some reason when I run that page with "Download all embedded resource", one 1MB image ( the main image on the page) doesn't download in the response. Why is that any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the image is linked in the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model), if it's referenced in CSS it might be the case JMeter won't recognize it, similar situation is described in [JMeter Bug 63048](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63048)

If this is the case - you can add another HTTP Request sampler for obtaining that particular image and put both samplers under the [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/JMeter-Transaction-controller-behavior/) to measure the cumulative time.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I think I should put both samplers under Parallel Controller, if I put them in Transaction Controller they will run sequentially. Right?

Comment: They need to be run sequentially, first main sampler gets the data and then embedded resources are being downloaded in 6 parallel threads

Comment: But the big image too should be downloaded parallelly with other resources. Am I wrong?